# Admin and User log in from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I was wondering if anyone could help me - I have successfully created a log in system allowing a user (student) to log in. My system also requires an admin log in, with the admin having privileges to view pages that the student does not. Both the admin and student information comes from two different tables. Below is the code I have used for the student log in (there are two different pages - users and login). I am stuck as to how to implement the admin log in. Any help is appreciated! 
(Admin will log in using 'adminnum' and 'adminpassword'.

***login.php***

```
<?php

include "core/init.php";
include "includes/content.php";

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$studentemail = $_POST ['studentemail'];
$studentpassword = $_POST ['studentpassword'];

if (empty($studentemail) === true || empty($studentpassword) === true) {
    $errors[] = "You need to enter an email address and password"; 
} else if (user_exists($studentemail) === false) {
    $errors[] = "We can't find that email address. Have you registered?";
} else {

    if (strlen($studentpassword) > 32) {
        $errors[] = 'Password too long';
        }

    $login = login($studentemail, $studentpassword);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'That email/password combination is incorrect';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['studentid'] = $login;
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}
} else {
$errors[] = 'No data received';
}
include "includes/overall/overall_header.php";
if (empty($errors) === false) {
?>
<h2> We tried to log you in, but...</h2>    

<?php
echo output_errors($errors);
}
?>
    <center><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Back" onclick="location.href='Login2.php'"></center>
<?php
include "includes/overall/overall_footerloggedout.php";
?>
```

***users.php***

```
<?php
function logged_in() {
return (isset($_SESSION['studentid'])) ? true : false;
}

function user_exists($studentemail) {
$studentemail = sanitize($studentemail);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`studentid`) FROM `student` WHERE `studentemail` 
         = '$studentemail'");
return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function studentid_from_student ($studentemail) {
$studentemail = sanitize($studentemail);
return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `studentid` FROM `student` WHERE      `studentemail` = '$studentemail'"), 0, 'studentid');
}
`function login($studentemail, $studentpassword) {
$studentid = studentid_from_student($studentemail);

$studentemail = sanitize($studentemail);
$studentpassword = md5($studentpassword);

return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`studentid`) FROM `student` WHERE   `studentemail` = '$studentemail' AND `studentpassword` = '$studentpassword'"), 0) == 1) ?   $studentid : false;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change your logic, extracting users and admins from two different table. Make them in only one table, but all users should contain column `flag` for example, where flag=1 is ADMIN and flag=0 is USER.

Comment: Why name the column "flag" and not something more useful like "is_admin"?  Poorly named fields are just as bad as poorly written code.

Comment: is_admin is too strict name, not flexible for more type users. I consider `flag` as much universal, but maybe user_type is better. Because in further use, you may have 10 type of users and only one of them will be admin. Why the column has to be is_admin then?

Comment: I presume I need two tables? One for students and one for Admins. I prefer to have two separate tables as they both have different column and store different data. When a new student is added they are added to the student table and given the type '0' and when a new admin is added they are added to the admin table and given the type '1'. I am just wondering how I could login either as a student or an admin using the values stored in the specified table. Would i need a SQL query with a join clause or is there an easier way?

Comment: You can either join queries or make a new query. Then you need another elseif, before break because now, if you don't find the user in users table, you tell them to go try again. Now you need, if you don't find the username in users table, to check if it's in admins table, and if true - navigate to admins page. If false, then tell them to log again. However, I still consider it bad practice, and flagging them as user types in users table - a better one. If you store diff info - make another table user_info and store as what info you want for each user/type

Comment: How do i go about joining queries as im unsure how to make a new query as im using functions. in the student table i have studentid, studentfirstname, studentsurname, studentemail, studentpassword, type, adminnum and in the admin table i have adminnum, adminfirstname, adminsurname, adminemail, adminpassword, type

Answer (score 0):

all i can suggest as i am not a php coder but have done some in the past is to add another field in your database where you will set levels of privileges for users (0 for normal members, 1 for admin). After you have done that just add it to your users script through php coding which i barely know. Hope that helps a little bit.